# Как удалить все, кроме букв, цифр и 1 пробела

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решаю задачу по обработке файла. В ходе тестов обнаружил, что при попадании спец. символов, двойных пробелов и прочего результат работы некорректный.

Как можно удалить из файла все, кроме букв, цифр и одинарных пробелов(двойные пробелы не нужны)?

Не получилось нагуглить такие функции в Python. Использовать регулярные выражения не очень хочу, т.к. в разных ОС свои спец символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверить, является ли строка цифрой или символом алфавита, можно с помощью метода [`isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) строки.

Для того, чтобы обработать одинарные пробелы, можно использовать метод [`isspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) строки или сравнивать непосредственно с пробелом, если требуется такая строгость.

Так как собирать строку сложением неэффективно, будем использовать список для хранения подходящих символов, после чего можно воспользоваться методом `join`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
result = []
for char in data:
    if char.isalnum():
        result.append(char)
    elif char.isspace() and (not result or not result[-1].isspace()):
        result.append(char)
print(''.join(result))
```

Comment: Я расшаривал файл сразу методом split() и если попадались не одинарные пробелы, а прочий мусор но ломалась логика, а здесь мы его посимвольный читаем и образуем "правильный" список, верно?

Comment: Просто, насколько я понял, он формирует список по одному символу, а можно ввести лобовую проверки типа это буква или пробел - пишем, а остальное мимо?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК На первый вопрос ответ: да, верно. Мы просто составляем новый список, в котором все символы удовлетворяют поставленным условиям.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Насчёт использования `split()` -- это зависит от точной постановки вопроса. `split()` делит строку по всем пробельным символам, в том числе и переносам строк и табуляции. Таким образом, мы теряем информацию о том, какие символы использовались между частями строки. Если это не проблема, и можно просто объединить все части строки пробелами, то ок. Но в любом случае, если хочется фильтровать спец символы, то придётся вручную проверять каждый символ в каждом блоке строки, т.е. сократится только второе условие.

Answer (score 0):

Кто любит коротко и неясно:

```
r = "aaa1 3434 sss ###  #ss #44"
print "".join([z for d in ' '.join(a for a in r.split()) for x in d for z in x if z.isalnum() or z ==' ']).replace("  ", " ")
'aaa1 3434 sss ss 44'
```

Comment: "Я это люблю" © )